# TensorFlow: SKCompat Depreciation Warning

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

NOTE: My first question on here. Pardon for lack of details or info. More than happy to clarify if needed.

I'm running TensorFlow 1.0.0 on Mac and I keep getting this warning when using the learn.Estimator class

> WARNING:tensorflow:From :25: calling
>   fit (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator)
>   with y is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
>   Instructions for updating: Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn
>   interface by moving into separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and
>   batch_size are only available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will
>   only accept input_fn. Example conversion:   est = Estimator(...) ->
>   est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))

I've tried looking this class up and there is zero information in regards to it. Full code is posted here

https://github.com/austinmwhaley/DeepFarm/blob/master/prototype_1.ipynb

Please let  me know if there is any other info that anyone needs

Comment: I have similar issue when following the [cnn_mnist tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py). Based on the Error Info, I tried something like `from tensorflow.contrib.learn.SKCompat import SKCompat` and them wrap the Estimator with `SKCompat()`. But it does not work...Error:"No module named SKCompat". Need some help too!

Answer (score 5):

You can import SKCompat from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python import SKCompat
```

And then wrap your estimator with SKCompat() e.g. like this:

```
classifier = SKCompat(tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(args))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you simply use the [updated Estimator API of TensorFlow r1.1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator)

The API for the model definition is quite similar with some small changes in parameters, return type or function name only. Here is an example that I have used:

```
def model_fn():
    def _build_model(features, labels, mode, params):
        # 1. Configure the model via TensorFlow operations
        # Connect the first hidden layer to input layer (features) with relu activation
        y = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features, num_outputs=64, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                              weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        y = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(y, num_outputs=64, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                              weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        y = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(y, num_outputs=1, activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
                                              weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

        predictions = y

        # 2. Define the loss function for training/evaluation
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN or mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
            loss = tf.reduce_mean((predictions - labels) ** 2)
        else:
            loss = None

        if mode != tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            eval_metric_ops = {
                "rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), predictions),
                "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), predictions),
                "precision": tf.metrics.precision(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), predictions)
            }
        else:
            eval_metric_ops = None

        # 3. Define the training operation/optimizer
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
                loss=loss,
                global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
                learning_rate=0.001,
                optimizer="Adam")
        else:
            train_op = None

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            predictions_dict = {"pred": predictions}
        else:
            predictions_dict = None

        # 5. Return predictions/loss/train_op/eval_metric_ops in ModelFnOps object
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          predictions=predictions_dict,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          train_op=train_op,
                                          eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
    return _build_model
```

And you can use this model then like this:

```
e = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn(), params=None)
e.train(input_fn=input_fn(), steps=1000)
```

An example of an input-function for TensorFlow r1.1 can be found in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792518/setting-batch-size-when-using-input-fn-for-tf-contrib-learn-estimator/43658096#43658096).