# setting batch_size when using input_fn for tf.contrib.learn.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the high-level Estimator on TF:

```
estim = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(...)
estim.fit ( some_input )
```

If *some_input* has `x`, `y`, and `batch_size`, the codes run but with a warning; so I tried to use `input_fn`, and managed to send `x`, `y` through this `input_fn`, but not to send the `batch_size`. Didn't find any example for it.

Could anyone share a simple example that uses `input_fn` as input to the `estim.fit` / `estim.evaluate`, and uses `batch_size` as well?

Do I have to use `tf.train.batch`? If so, how does it merge into the higher-level implementation (`tf.layers`) - I don't know the graph's tf.Graph() or session?

Below is the warning I got:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py:657: calling evaluate
>
> (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with y is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
>
> Instructions for updating:
>   Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
>   separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
>   available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
>
> Example conversion:
>
> est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))

Comment: For anyone who may encounter a problem with the _input_fn_ as well in the future (currently I find the documentation not so much self explanatory) - found a well explained example, in the following [link](http://blog.mdda.net/ai/2017/02/25/estimator-input-fn).

Answer (score 4):

The [link provided in Roi's own comment](http://blog.mdda.net/ai/2017/02/25/estimator-input-fn) was indeed really helpful. Since I was struggling with the same question as well for a while, I would like to summarize the answer provided by the link above as a reference:

```
def batched_input_fn(dataset_x, dataset_y, batch_size):
    def _input_fn():
        all_x = tf.constant(dataset_x, shape=dataset_x.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
        all_y = tf.constant(dataset_y, shape=dataset_y.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
        sliced_input = tf.train.slice_input_producer([all_x, all_y])
        return tf.train.batch(sliced_input, batch_size=batch_size)
    return _input_fn
```

This can then be used like this example (using TensorFlow v1.1):

```
model = CustomModel(FLAGS.learning_rate)
estimator= tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model.build(), params=model.params())

estimator.train(input_fn=batched_input_fn(
       train.features, 
       train.labels,
       FLAGS.batch_size),
    steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
```

Unfortunately, this approach is about **10x slower** compared to manual feeding (using TensorFlows low-level API) or compared to using the whole dataset with `train.shape[0] == batch_size` and not using `train.sliced_input_producer()` and `train.batch()` at all. At least on my machine (CPU only). I'm really wondering why this approach is so slow. Any ideas?

**Edited:**

I could speed it up a bit by using `num_threads` > 1 as a parameter for `train.batch()`. On a VM with 2 CPUs, I'm able to double the performance using this batching mechanism compared to the default `num_threads=1`. But still, it is **5x slower** than manual feeding.
But results might be different on a native system or a system that uses all CPU cores for the input-pipeline and the GPU for the model computation. Would be great if somebody could post his results in the comments.