# How to update the code?

Tags: tensorflow, deprecated

I am running the code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py. It has the following code:

```
mnist_classifier.fit(
  x=train_data,
  y=train_labels,
  batch_size=100,
  steps=20000,
  monitors=[logging_hook])
eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(
  x=eval_data, y=eval_labels, metrics=metrics)
```

But there are some warnings about deprecated parameters(x, y, batch_size) of mnist_classifier.fit() and mnist_classifier.evaluate(). So, what is the new way to call the two function?

Part of the warnings:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From mnist.py:109: calling BaseEstimator.evaluate (from 
tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with x is 
deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
Instructions for updating:
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
  est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
WARNING:tensorflow:From mnist.py:109: calling BaseEstimator.evaluate (from 
tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with y is 
deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
Instructions for updating:
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
  est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
```

Comment: mind sharing the warnings, so we don't have to execute the code?

Comment: This blogpost might help: http://blog.mdda.net/ai/2017/02/25/estimator-input-fn -- if it does it would be great if someone could transform that information into an answer.

Comment: I think the blog above  does solve the problem by using python lambda expression. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow: SKCompat Depreciation Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451062/tensorflow-skcompat-depreciation-warning)